# What's the meaning of the word glib?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, adjectives

I've been studying English for a lot of time and if there's a word that I've always struggled to understand, this word is "glib". I've read multiple definitions of this word on various dictionaries, but I still can't fully get it.

[CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/glib) has, for instance,

> **glib**: speaking or spoken in a confident way, but without careful thought or honesty:
>
> - *No one was convinced by his glib answers/explanations*.

[Collins Cobuild](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/glib) , on the other hand, gives:

> **glib**: If you describe what someone says as glib, you disapprove of it because it implies that something is simple or easy, or that there
> are no problems involved, when this is not the case.

So, the word glib is usually defined as a way of talking that is smooth, ready, fluent, confident, smart, easy ... but that at the same time do not show much thought, it's shallow, trivializing, lacks understanding ... To me this is ever so confusing. It seems that these two things don't go well together. I wouldn't use it for example to define the way that a salesperson talks, since I wouldn't say that it lacks understanding and that it doesn't show much thoughts.

I mean, it seems to be referring to someone that is very well-spoken, has the gift of gab, silver-tongued ... so everything that I would associate to being clever, competent, knowledgeable ... but instead they are flippant, facile and maybe even dim.

Did I get it? Maybe I'm puzzled because in my native tongue, that's Italian, I can't find anything that is quite the same. I would be very grateful to whoever will provide me with some examples of ways of talking that you guys find to be glib.

Comment: ***glibness*** implies ***fluency*** and ***readiness***. But it's nearly always used "contemptuously", ***implying lack of thought or of sincerity***. Those same negative implications would apply if we refer to a salesman's ***smooth** presentation* or ***slick** patter,* though.

Comment: Just check out some of my comments here -- they're mostly glib.

Comment: @HotLicks: I suggest that actually you've posted more comments here that would be better described as *sincere, thoughtful, insightful* (the best I can come up with for "antonyms of the usual implications of **glib**").

Comment: I would say that being **glib** includes the ability to skip over tricky areas of an argument: to make something seem *plausible* when it actually isn't.

Comment: In the movie *Genius*, Guy Pierce (who is playing F Scott Fitzgerald) says at one point to Jude Law (who is playing Thomas Wolfe): _Don't get glib with me_. Guy is being slippery in his talk and trying to dodge the real point, which revolves around his fractured relationship with Colin Firth (who is playing Max Perkins). Sorry if I used a sledgehammer to crack a nut but i hope it helps.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: So it's either a lack of thought or insincerity? It makes sense that a salesman is fluent and insincere, but I would not say that this implies a lack of thought. I don't know, it's still strange to me since "lack of thought" and "insincerity" are two very different things so this would mean that glib could assume very different meanings depending on the context.

Comment: @Weather Vane: I still don't understand why it is linked to a lack of thought though, since it seems to be the opposite thing.

Comment: @user405662: Again, I still can't see a lack of thought and/or understanding.

Comment: Anyway, thank you for your replies I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Valerio: If you get a ***glib*** response to a complaint, you're being ***fobbed off***. Don't get too hung up on whether the person fobbing you off is actually *thinking* very hard about how they react to you. What matters is they're treating you casually / carelessly, and ***not solving your problem***.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A good question. Showing dictionary definitions (which should accompany the question) would in itself not resolve this. Polysemy and perhaps hypernymy is going on.

Perhaps [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/glib) best illustrates the problem (I've re-ordered to help a logical approach) (and note that the speaker *or* what they say may be labelled *glib*):

> *Definition of* **glib**
>
> - 1a: showing little forethought or preparation : OFFHAND *glib answers*
> - c: lacking depth and substance : SUPERFICIAL
> - b: marked by ease and informality : NONCHALANT *glib solutions to knotty problems*

So (a) not given what others might consider necessary forethought **and/or** (b) lacking depth and real substance (probably, if applicable,  as a consequence of (a)) **and/or** marked by ease of speaking or decision-making (an obviously somewhat misleading skill, if senses (a) and (b) also apply).

These senses are conflated, with perhaps a hint at temporal re-ordering (fluency leading to sloppiness), in M-W's sense (2):

> - 2: marked by ease and fluency in speaking or writing often to the point of being insincere or deceitful *a glib politician*

Comment: I am terribly tempted to DV, as the Q shows no research, and the meanings are in **General Reference**...

Comment: @Cascabel It would be a little hard to DV (I presume downvote rather than God willing). The question is quite delightfully worded and reveals a deal of delicate thought going well beyond plodding dictionary work.

Comment: Woe unto you when all men think well of you.

Comment: @Anton Unless you are not aware, Edwin has a long history of DVing answers to questions which 1) show no research 2) can be found in a **General Reference**...as he did to one of mine just yesterday. You yourself have been the target of such. Fair is fair.//...and now Edwin just edited/manipulated the Q to get around the "research required" criteria...I give up, this is not right. That said...I DID NOT DV the answer...I don't think it is right to punish the answerer for posting a good answer to a questionable question. That's my point.

Comment: The answer (to the recent question) of yours I DVd was to be found in its entirety in a work considered a GR in the GR list in Meta. Here, I've sorted through and analysed various overlapping .../... conflicting definitions in various recommended reference works. I've also edited OP to clearly show the problem Valerio has identified (quite acceptable, in fact recommended for potentially decent questions)  'This is not right' is what is not right.

Comment: As is this question...you seem to have some shades of grey that not all of us are privy to...and you manipulated the Q to bring it on-topic. // The answer to that question may have been found in Urban Dictionary, but many people here feel that is a dodgy source.  I am just asking that you be a little less judgemental. I actually liked this question, but did not answer because I thought users like you would shut me down.

Comment: (1) ["make someone" meaning](https://www.google.co.uk/search?source=hp&ei=HELJX-HoPLKXlwTT-534DA&q=%22make+someone%22+meaning&oq=%22make+someone%22+meaning&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzICCAAyBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB46EQguELEDEIMBEMcBEKMCEJMCOgUIABCxAzoICAAQsQMQgwE6CwguELEDEMcBEKMCOggILhCxAxCDAToFCC4QsQM6BwgAELEDEAo6CAguELEDEJMCOgIILjoFCC4QkwJQthBYpElgy0xoAHAAeACAAcgBiAGJD5IBBjE2LjUuMZgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXo&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjh5ruoy7LtAhWyy4UKHdN9B88Q4dUDCAk&uact=5) and then ...

Comment: (2) ['**make someone** 
tv. to identify someone. _The cop stared at Bart and tried to make him, but failed to identify him and let him go._

McGraw-Hill's Dictionary of American Slang and Colloquial Expressions'](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/make+someone) QED. Less than a minute.

Comment: 1) does not provide the necessary definitions 2) that on the list of General Reference? The chat monster is complaining. All I am asking is that you be a little nicer in your treatment of answerers, and not just automatically VTC the Q, or DV an answer. Good nite...I am outa here.

Comment: Why don't you check?

Comment: @Cascabel Thank you. Oh dear! I didn't mean to start general discussion from a question I had not even answered. I realised you had considerately refrained from DV. You now reinforce my impressions of others' over-negative behaviour. One shard of negativity does more harm than the good of ten positive comments. Some commentators shut more doors than they ever open. I have long accepted that, much as I deplore judgmental attitudes here (occasionally to the point where I felt I would give up on the site), I must accept the right of others to adopt them. Thank you again. Maybe this is for meta.

Comment: @Anton You may have a point there, about taking it to meta. From time to time, I drop out of the the culture, and when I come back, well,  there seem to be very different political thoughts.

Comment: @Anton Are you saying that one should not DV what one considers are merely LMGTFY answers to questions not even mentioning any research? Isn't site integrity important? There are many other websites with a less academic mission-statement and less peer review where standards are perhaps not considered to be so important.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I am not adopting such a position. I have the impression that you and I agree in principles and merely differ in degree or in the greyness of thresholds between black and white. I have found the grey areas the most interesting; their examination offers insights into the blacks and whites. The quasi-academic and reflective nature of this site is excellent. But, as in teaching, I try to err on the side of encouragement rather than dismissal. Too ready a dismissal  may do more harm to a particular individual than it does for the general integrity and status of the site. Thank you.

Comment: @Anton But the mission statement is primarily to build up a comprehensive but non-bloated repository of accepted English language. Compare the compilation of a dictionary or grammar. Editing _needs_ to be of the hard-pruning variety. It's an atypical site, not primarily a Q & A, 'address/solve problems at every level and however much they flout the regulations' site. There are plenty of chat-type English  sites to help everyman; is it too much to expect just one that aims for rigorous standards? And 'This question can be answered by a single entry in a general reference work' always affronts.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth your emphasis is therefore reasonably and commendably on the “product” (the repository) whereas most of what I see here is the “process” of people using the site, and not much by way of  people referring to the product. I suppose it is all akin to the development of Law by Case Law. We need both.

Comment: @Anton You're not taking on board the fact that it's not 'my emphasis'; to my knowledge, it's what ELU has maintained since its inception. Of course, rudeness is anathema, but too many people take offense rather than say 'I disagree that this is general reference because ...'. From the Help Center: 'Answer well-asked questions'. I'd modify this, as some questions lacking research can be edited to make them very appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Glib

Glib means 'slides off the tongue' (this popped into my head, from my uncanny intuitive knowledge of English, but is confirmed by the etymology of 'glib' which is Germanic, from 'slimy'.)

Glib, is where phrases slip from someone's mouth very easily, but are not backed up by substance, possibly by truth, or by effort.

A glib phrase slides instantly, but the sayer will squirm away before having to deliver the substance or promise of what was said.

Examples:

The salesman's glib comment that 'a loud clanking sound was normal in 2008 models, and nothing to worry about', worried Jane - who could not imagine the salesman coming out on a cold and windy night, to pick her up in her broken vehicle.

'Let them eat cake!' declared Marie Antionette, queen of France, in response to her subjects rioting, due to lack of bread. Her glib comment, apparently revealing a complete lack of awareness of existence outside of her comfortable palace, led to the French Revolution, her demise, and the ultimate demise of the French royalty.

Etymology:
A shortening of either English glibbery (“slippery”) or its source, Low German glibberig, glibberich (“slippery”) / Dutch glibberig (“slippery”).

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/glib